# Do wattles have the same ability to fix nitrogen from air as other legumes?

Tags: nitrogen, legumes

Do wattles (roughly Australian *[Acacia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacia)* species) have the same ability as other members of the [*Fabaceae*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabaceae) (legume) family to fix nitrogen from air via symbiosis with soil bacteria? For instance, it's well known that peas and beans do, but what about the more tree-like legumes?

It's not a completely academic question for me. I'm wondering if planting wattles would be a useful way to gradually improve the surrounding soil by adding nitrogen, while being a chance to plant native species.

[image: Wattle: Acacia buxifolia]

([*Acacia buxifolia* image source](http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/journal/flickr-photo-of-the-week-wattle-tree.htm))

Comment: Do the roots have small tubers like on this image? [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Faboideae_root_nodules_Taub42.png](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Faboideae_root_nodules_Taub42.png)

If they do, then I would think they have soil bacterias (Rhizobium) for nitrogen enrichment.

Comment: At least some acacia's are allelopathic - they inhibit germination of other plants and _may_ otherwise discourage growth.  Raking up any leaf litter _may_ keep this from happening.  I can't find a good hands-on reference on this, but it's described extensively in academic literature.  And I'm in the wrong climate, so I've no experience myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that this is one of the defining points of the *Fabaceae*. Trees in this group definitely act like legumes - other examples include mesquite and Texas red bud. As it happens, only a couple of weeks ago I was talking about plant diversity with MrsWinwaed - one of the ones I mentioned were the *Fabaceae* which include clover, beans, and mesquite - three quite different looking plants!

Another feature of them is they usually have high protein levels (eg. beans) due to the extra nitrogen made available by the nodules. *Acacia* are known for having high protein, so I think it is safe to say they do fix nitrogen in reasonable quantities.

Comment: Excellent explanation and thanks! Doubt was introduced into my mind because I read somewhere (Wikipedia I think) that *most* Fabaceae fix nitrogren in this way, but couldn't find out much about what exclusions there are or why.